# Deleting list with pointers and also the object must be cleared

Tags: c++, list, object, erase

Below is the sameple c++ code for illustrating my problem
 I am aware about other working approaches but interested to know if the below code is wrong?

```
Void pupulatelist()
{
   //populating the list with some int pointers,in actual i have some other objects to delete when accessed each time.
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
    {
         int *p = new int(i);
         list.push_back(p);
    }  
   //want to delete and erase the contents of the above list
   // if i dont use erase my actual code is crashing.  

    for(std::list<int *>::iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
       delete(*iter);    
       list.erase(iter--);
     }  
 }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `list.erase` and call `list.clear` after the loop instead. (Also, don't use a type name as a variable name.)

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to leave the `list.erase` out of your for loop and just call `list.clear` when you're all done.

If you want to keep the for loop, it needs to be fixed.  It should go like this:

```
for (auto iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end();) {
    delete *iter;
    iter = list.erase(iter);
}
```

`erase` returns an iterator to the element following the one that is erased, so that you don't need to increment in the loop.  Also, your original loop would decrement iter to point before the start of list which is undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code again, can you please check it and let me know if it still has the problem. Merely deleting the pointer will not clear the object if i am not wrong. so i am deleting the object and clearing it.

Comment: @lokeshkondi You're not handling the iterator right when erasing; check my code again.  Since you're getting rid of everything you're better off not erasing in the loop and calling `clear` when the loop is done.